# BASH Reading all keys from a .properties file doesn't display last key

Tags: bash, shell

I have a `web.properties` file that contains a bunch of key values.

```
FIRST="true"
SECOND="true"
THIRD="true"
```

I am writing a bash script to display all of the keys from the `web.properties` file

**myscript.sh**

```
file="web.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]; then
  echo "file found"

  while IFS='=' read -r key value
  do
    echo "Found ${key}"
  done < "$file"
  else
  echo "$file not found."
fi
```

**Output:**

```
FIRST
SECOND
```

As you can see, `THIRD` is left out. If I modify my `web.properties` file to have an extra return

**web.properties**

```
FIRST="true"
SECOND="true"
THIRD="true"
//stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do an empty line in code formatting, so pretend this doesn't exist
```

My output is:

```
FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
```

I would like my bash script to work in both scenarios as the file gets edited programmatically and manually and so an IDE might or might not have that trailing space., with the trailing carriage return or without it. Thoughts?

Comment: A valid POSIX text file always ends with a newline; `web.properties` apparently does not.

Comment: @chepner I wasn't aware of that. Unfortunately, intelliJ IDEA makes it easy to not end with a newline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I upvoted [@choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49763621/96588) already, this is another variant:

```
while IFS== read key value || [[ -n "$value" ]]
do
    echo "$key : $value"
done < "$file"
```

In other words, if `read` returns 0 *or* `read` was able to read a non-empty line but failed otherwise, `do`. In that sense it's shorter and IMO a bit clearer.

There is a catch with the above code, however. The ideal implementation should evaluate the `while` statement to true if and only if one of the following is true:

1. `read` succeeds and therefore must have populated `key` and `value`.
2. `read` fails after populating `key` and `value` specifically because EOF was reached.

Compare this to the above implementation which evaluates the `while` statement to true if the first condition is true or `read` fails *for any reason* as long as `value` is populated afterwards. These reasons are described in `help read`:

> The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out (in which case it's greater than 128), a variable assignment error occurs, or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.

This may not even be an exhaustive list. What this means is that if (for example) there's an error reading the input file, but `read` either doesn't clear the variables or repopulates them in case of such errors, then the code will *ignore* this much more serious error condition and continue as if nothing untoward had happened. This sort of careless handling of error conditions can lead to extremely hard to debug problems, even in such a simple piece of code as this, and is one reason [Bash is completely unsuitable for anything complex](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses).

Comment: Hm. Can't get that to run.

My output:
file found
./test.sh: file: No such file or directory

Comment: Changed the last line to `done < "$file"` and now it works! Thanks so much. Could you explain the "catch" once more? I'm failing to see a case where this could go wrong? Do you mean if there's a key but no value?

Comment: so what is alternative to bash then

Answer (score 5):

Output an additional newline at the end every time, ignore empty lines:

```
while IFS== read key value ; do
    if [[ -z $key ]] ; then
        continue
    fi
    echo "$key : $value"
done < <(cat file; echo)
```